# How can I GET a page with a generated sessionID parameter?

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to login into a [website](https://studentweb.studentenheim.at/studentWeb/login) and then scrape a certain element from that page. I already know how to POST the username, password and the verification token, however, I can't GET the next page because its URL has a sessionID parameter which seems to be generated each time on the server-side (obviously? sry, I'm a noob)

I used [this](https://linuxhint.com/logging_into_websites_python/) tutorial for the login and already tried the GET request without the sessionID, which responds with an HTTP 500

```py
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with Session() as s:
    site = s.get("https://studentweb.studentenheim.at/studentWeb/login")
    bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
    token = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"__RequestVerificationToken"})["value"]
    login_data = {"Username":"qwertz","Password":"123456","__RequestVerificationToken":token}
    s.post("https://studentweb.studentenheim.at/studentWeb/login",login_data)
    home_page = s.get("https://studentweb.studentenheim.at/studentWeb/Waitinglist")
    print(home_page)
```

Comment: POST requests also provide responses, this response will probably have the SessionID you need, if you are sending to the correct place with correct credentials, else it will raise 4xx or 5xx errors.

Comment: Add headers and verify=False in your requests.